# Outlook 2003 IMAP Sent Folder Mark As Read (VBA Help)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap

I know. I know. The program is antiquated. I have a friend that got a smart phone and I changed his email on Outlook 2003 to be IMAP (rather than POP3) so that everything is on the server and both his computer and phone will be synced together and everything the same.

I figured out how to create a rule to make the sent items in Outlook 2003 show up in the sent items in the IMAP sent folder, but they are marked as unread as they show up in there.

Apparently, the only way around is by using VBA and entering codes. That's where I get lost: http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/mark-items-read/

I found the ThisOutlookSession module, but I'm confused when the article says,

> Change this line: Set Items = GetFolderPath("New PST\SentItems").Items
>   to reflect the data file name in the folder list and the folder name
>   you are moving the sent item to.

How do I know what the data file name is? The article also tells me to use "the code" from this page: http://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/

Again, I need to edit folder paths or whatever... which code do I use and what folder path do I put in?

Comment: Go to  >Tools >Account Settings' select your IMAP account, click "Change", then "More Settings". You should see a "Sent Items" should be an option there

Comment: If you can, you should encourage them to switch to a mail client that truly supports IMAP. Even in OL2013, IMAP support is terrible, in OL2003 it was a lot worse.